# Move image files according to watermark identified by a neural network

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, file-system, neural-network

I have created a neural network that can identify watermarks and can classify them to which company do they belong. Now I created a script that will identify watermark from a folder and move them to different folders where they belong. But this script is quite slow and consumes too much RAM. What should i do to improvise it?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import time 
import glob
import shutil
import csv
d = glob.glob("colabData/Krishna/*.jpg")
print("Total Number of Images are :" ,len(d))

count = 0
final_data = []
def convertToRGB(img): 
    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

for images in d:
    count += 1
    test1 = cv2.imread(images)
    sublist = []
    output = test1.copy()
    image = cv2.resize(test1, (96, 96))
    image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

    model = load_model("colabData/pokedex.model")
    lb = pickle.loads(open("colabData/lb.pickle", "rb").read())
    proba = model.predict(image)
    idx = np.argmax(proba)
    label = lb.classes_[idx]
    if not os.path.exists(label):
        os.makedirs(label)
    sublist.append(label)
    if label=="Commonfloor":
        shutil.move(images, "colabData/commonfloorr")
        print("WaterMark is Available", images, label)
    elif label=="Housing":
        shutil.move(images, "colabData/housingg")
        print("WaterMark is Available", images, label)
    elif label=="Sulekha":
        shutil.move(images, "colabData/sulekhaa")
        print("WaterMark is Available", images, label)
    elif label=="Magicbricks":
        shutil.move(images, "colabData/magicbrickss")
        print("WaterMark is Available",images, label)
    elif label=="Property_Wala":
        shutil.move(images, "colabData/propertywalaa")
        print("WaterMark is Available", images, label)
    elif label=="Non-Watermark":
        shutil.move(images, "colabData/nonwatermarkk")
        print("WaterMark is Not Available", images, label)
    elif label=="FloorPlans":
        shutil.move(images, "colabData/floorplann")
        print("WaterMark is Not Available", images, label)
    elif label=="MasterPlan":
        shutil.move(images, "colabData/masterplann")
        print("WaterMark is Not Available", images, label)
    else:
        print("Unable to classify")
    print(count)
    final_data.append(sublist)

filename = "data.csv"
with open("colabData/"+filename,'w') as csvfile:
    csvfile = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvfile.writerow("")
    for i in range(0, len( final_data )):
        csvfile.writerow( final_data[i]  )
```